# Trying to understand error upon using deleted on imported static method

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand behavior of pointer in my code here, my question is toward the bottom code that i have commented out and None of the information I found answered following question that I have. My questions is why compiler giving me error that uninitialized variable app is used,  and also what will be the good practice for writing my code and why i can't use delete app here. I am using visual studio 2017

**File Application.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace Test
{
    class _declspec(dllexport)Application
    {
    public:
        Application();
        ~Application();
        static void Run();
    };
}
```

**File Application.cpp**

```
#pragma once

    #include "Application.h"
    
    namespace Test {
        Application::Application() {
    
        }
        Application::~Application() {
    
        }
    
        void Application::Run() {
            while (true);
        }
    }
```

**File SandboxApp.cpp**

```
namespace Test 
{
    __declspec(dllimport)class Application 
    {
    public:
        static void Run();
        //may be virtual is must here?
        ~Application();
    };
}

int main() 
{
    

    /* this work Test::Application t;
    t.~Application();*/

    Test::Application app;
    app.Run();

    app.~Application();
    // why the lines below gives error even though its probably never going to reach even if the 
    //application is closed
    
    /*Test::Application* app;
    app->Run();*/
    
    //delete app; use this or the below one both give error

    //app->~Application();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Extra**
i still want to know why upon removing everything inside the main and adding the last part of my code gives a compiler error, I want to know why I can't do that I want to understand behavior of pointer in the last part of my code, so that it make sense to me, I know i shouldn't but why? and also if just use the bottom two lines of my code without delete app; or app->~Application(); my code still work. I mean to say if I just use Test::Application* app; app->Run(); compiler don't give any error and my code works but why i can't use delete app; ?

```
Test::Application* app;
    app->Run();
    
    delete app; use this or the below one both give error

    app->~Application();
```

Comment: In your commented out code, you never initialize `app`.  Also, unrelated but you probably do not want to explicitly call the destructor.

Comment: I have added the missing code.

Comment: The commented code in `main` has an uninitialized variable (`app`).  The compiler diagnostic is very clear.  What does your C++ book say about initializing variables?

Comment: Calling the destructor manually seems reckless. That'll be called for you automatically when that instance falls out of scope.

Comment: Also `run()` is a `static` function meaning it should be `Test::Application.run()`. I don't know why it's flagged as `static`, that's surely a mistake, but since it is you can't call it via `app`.

Comment: Look closely at the excellent hints that earlier commenters have been giving you. Here's your first problem ... Test::Application* app = new Test::Application(); The existing comments clearly indicate other issues that you must / should deal with.

Comment: Best practise would be to write this code `int main() { Test::Application app; app.Run(); }` That's all you need, you're making things too complicated. You don't need pointers, you don't need to call a destructor.

Comment: @StephenNewell I want to know why i can't use this code and whats going on behind the scene a bit for the following code

Test::Application* app;
    app->Run();
    
    delete app; use this or the below one both give error

    app->~Application();

Comment: @john I also realized it myself but i still want to know why upon removing everything inside the main and adding the last part of my code gives a compiler error, I want to know why I can't do that I want to understand behavior of pointer in the last part of my code, so that it make sense to me, I know i shouldn't but why?

Comment: @Apachi Like the error said the pointer is *uninitialised*. You have to make the pointer point at an object. John Sheridan showed you the way to do that. `Test::Application* app = new Test::Application();`

Comment: @Apachi before you can delete an object you must first create it (with new). As everyone has been indicating to you, you have declared app as a pointer but you have not initialised it. Test::Application *app = new Test::Application(); will create a new Application object and assign it to your app variable. The reason that app->Run() works for you even though app is not pointing to an Application object  the Run method is declared as static. Finally, you should never call the destructor directly on an object. Deleting the object (delete app) will cause its destructor to be invoked.

Comment: @JohnSheridan , jhon    t h a n k s    for the help, I think i got it. I have to check couple my documents again.One more question, is it okay for me to use delete app; instead of app.~Application();. the lesson i was following teaches me to delete app; not exactly the way i have coded but quite similar.

Comment: Never call the destructor directly app.~Application(); If you are using pointers to objects that you have created with new then use delete. If you have objects that were not created with new then simply let them go out of scope. Their destructor will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's contribution

```
Test::Application app;
app.Run();
```

^ This works because it's not a pointer, it's an object which is initialized.

```
Test::Application* app;
app->Run();
```

^ This does work, and it made me confused because it is working, and visual studio is not giving any warning or error either, its a beginner nightmare right there, why visual sutdio is even letting me use this symbol( -> )here. but it will give error only if any of the next line is added e.g `delete app;`

```
Test::Application* app;
app->Run();
delete app;
```

^ This does not work and will give error only if you add e.g `delete app;`But why? **Answer** is before you can delete an object you must first create it (with new). As everyone has been indicating me, I have declared app as a pointer but have not initialised it. `Test::Application *app = new Test::Application();` will create a new Application object and assign it to your app variable. The reason that `app->Run()` works for me even though app is not pointing to an Application object the Run method is declared as static, <-- Here this way i think I am still missing something. And *according* to ***learncpp dot com***,

**Static member functions have no Asterisk symbol(*)this pointer**

> Static member functions have two interesting quirks worth noting.
> First, because static member functions are not attached to an object,
> they have no this pointer! This makes sense when you think about it --
> the this pointer always points to the object that the member function
> is working on. Static member functions do not work on an object, so
> the this pointer is not needed.
>
> Second, static member functions can directly access other static
> members (variables or functions), but not non-static members. This is
> because non-static members must belong to a class object, and static
> member functions have no class object to work with!

Finally, you should never call the destructor directly on an object. Deleting the object (delete app) will cause its destructor to be invoked.

To make my `int main` code work i followed the provided information and done this:

```
Test::Application* app = new Test::Application;
app->Run();
delete app;
```

Answer (score 0):

app is a pointer and it's not initialized, your IDE is protecting you from undefined behaviour.

```
Test::Application app;
app.Run();
```

^ This works because it's not a pointer, it's an object which is initialized.

```
Test::Application* app;
app->Run();
```

^ This does not work because your pointer isn't initalized.

To make the bottom code work, do this:

```
Test::Application* app = new Test::Application;
app->Run();
```